# How to get the path back most efficiently in A* algorithm

Tags: python, graph, nodes, path-finding, a-star

I am working on finding the shortest path in a maze and would like someone to look over my code and comment how to make it better as well as say what would be the most efficient way to get the path back.

```
def aStarSearch(currentNode, endNode):
    openList = []
    closedList = []
    currentNode.set_g(0) #cost so far
    currentNode.set_h(endNode.return_y(), endNode.return_x()) #estimated euclidean distance
    currentNode.set_f((currentNode.get_g() + currentNode.get_h())) #total cost
    openList.append(currentNode)
    closedList.append(currentNode)

    while openList != []:
        for node in openList:
            if node.get_f() <= currentNode.get_f(): #node with smaller total cost becomes current node
                currentNode = node
                currentNode.set_h(endNode.return_y(), endNode.return_x()) #estimated euclidean distance
                currentNode.set_f((currentNode.get_g() + currentNode.get_h())) #total cost
        draw_maze(endNode)
        neighbours = return_Neighbours(currentNode)
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            neighbour.set_f(neighbour.get_g() + neighbour.get_h()) #calculate the f cost     
            if neighbour.get_g() <= currentNode.get_g() and neighbour in closedList: #if the neighbours cost is smaller and in closed list mean already visited,should backtrack
                openList.append(neighbour)
                closedList.remove(neighbour)
                neighbour.set_colour((255,0,255))
            elif currentNode.get_g() <= neighbour.get_g() and neighbour in openList: #it has not been already visited but seen so g is smaller
                neighbour.set_g(currentNode.get_g()) #change g because g is previous cost
                closedList.append(neighbour)
                neighbour.set_colour((255,255,0))
            elif neighbour not in openList or closedList: #not visited yet, needs to be appended, calculate h because cannot find another place to do that
                openList.append(neighbour)
                neighbour.set_h(endNode.return_x(), endNode.return_y())
                neighbour.set_colour((0,255,255))
        if currentNode.get_vector() == endNode.get_vector():
            return closedList
```

Comment: Can you provide the remainder of the code to test this?

Comment: Yes rest of code please, the most important thing is how you deal with your openList and get the highest F node.